# What is the right way to import a contract type that uses an interface in hardhat?

Tags: hardhat, testing, hardhat-deploy, interfaces, typescript

I have a contract with an interface that I want to test with hardhat
the contract looks like this

```
interface IGame {
    function play(uint guess) external;
}

contract Test {
    address private owner;
    IGame gameContract;
....
}
```

So when I import its type into the test file I receive an error telling that the function from the interface is absent....

*Property 'play' is missing in type 'BaseContract & Omit<ContractInterface, keyof BaseContract>' but required in type 'Game'*

What's the right way of fixing it? Thank you

using the this.contract instead of its type? But the code would become harder to read... is there a way without using this.? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right way to do it is to deployContract('ONLY THE CONTRACT NAME WITHOUT THE PATH gives you the needed interface')